# Load a haml view into layout on Ajax request through Sinatra controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, sinatra, haml

i'm implementing a live-search-function into my page.. I have the following simplified sinatra controller

```
get '/search_item/:for' do
//do some search stuff
haml :search_item,:layout => (request.xhr? ? false : :layout),
                  :locals => {  :found_items => queried_items,
                                :current_user => current_user,
                                } 
end
```

then I have a layout.haml file with the input field

```
%input(type="text" id="search_query" name="search_query"  size="15" value="")
```

and the the two divs

```
#content
    = yield

#results(style="display=none")
```

now starts my problem I need a jquery/javascript function to send the xhr or a json request,
use the input in the sinatra controller to generate the search_item view which then should be rendered/loaded in the layout #results div without refreshing the whole page. By now I have something like:

```
:javascript
 $(function() {
 $("#search_query").keyup(function(){
    var q = $("#search_query").val();
    if(q != ""){
----------- this is the problem part -------------
    $.get('/search_item/'+q, function(data) {
    $('#results').html(data);})
--------------------------------------------------
    $("#content").css("display","none");
    $("#results").css("display","inline");

    }
    else{
    $("#content").css("display","inline");
    $("#results").css("display","none");
    }}); });
```

Is there a way of doing it like this simply loading the routed haml view into the div

```
    var url = "/search_item/"+q;
    $('#results').load(url);
```

I tried that but its not working..

I am not using rails!
So i have three questions:

1. How do I properly send the request on keyup to sinatra and how can i use it there?
2. How do I then without refreshing render the search_item.haml into the layout.haml #results div.
3. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I properly send the request on keyup to sinatra and how can i use it there?

You need to specify the data type as html in your `$.get()`

> How do I then without refreshing render the search_item.haml into the layout.haml #results div

First you need to compile you haml view into html (browsers don't support haml, but haml compiles to html/erb templates which you are already doing!), and then your best approach is likely to use a `$('some_selector').append( data_recieved_from_get_call)`, or `$('some_selector').html( data_recieved_from_get_call)`.

> Is there a more elegant way to do it?

I would recommend checking out [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), it's sort of javascript framework for managing single a page UI.

Once you get a handle on it, I'd recommend checking out [backbone.marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/). You end up reinventing the wheel a lot with just backbone, so once you understand how backbone works, this will really enable to be productive with it.

Last but not least, [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/).  It's just so much more readable!

These three things will take some time to get an understanding of but it's worth it!!

Comment: thanks for your answer :) !How exactly do i specify html in the $.get() and how do I render the haml view to html in the sinatra controller. You see I get a HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error as Response to my xhr requests. What might that be?

Comment: You specify it as third argument, see the [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), and basically that just tell the javascript how to handle in the incoming data. The `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` is a problem on your server side when you make your request to `'/search_item/'+q`, I notice you are not using the `:for` or which you are passing from the `q` var in your javascript.  What does the _sinatra_ error log say when you make a request to that address?

Comment: Damn.. I should have had a look at the sinatra log. it shows that the haml file doesn't compile correctly due to an uninitialized variable. Big thanks for your help. problem solved.